# MySQL - Find result that have children values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table structure:

**product_skus table**

```
| id |
| 1  | 
...
```

**product_sku_values table**

```
| product_sku_id | value_id |
| 1              | 1        |
| 1              | 2        |
| 1              | 3        |
...
```

I need the query to find the `product_sku_id`, having the three values ID's (`1`, `2`, and `3`).

I'm trying with this query:

```
select product_sku_id from product_sku_values
    where product_sku_values.value_id = 1
    or    product_sku_values.value_id = 2
    or    product_sku_values.value_id = 3
    group by product_sku_id
    having product_sku_id = 1
```

How can I do that? I'm trying lot of possibilities but no one give me the ID that I need. Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a canonical method:

```
select psv.product_sku_id
from product_sku_values psv
where psv.value_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by psv.product_sku_id
having count(distinct psv.value_id) = 3;
```

If you know that `product_sku_values` have no duplicates, then use `count(*)` in the `having` clause.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `group by` clause to get all the possible values, e.g.:

```
select product_sku_id, group_concat(value_id) 
from product_sku_values
group by product_sku_id;
```

If you are only interested in value_id 1,2 and 3 then you can add one `where` clause, e.g:

```
select product_sku_id, group_concat(value_id)
from product_sku_values
where value_id in (1,2,3)
group by product_sku_id;
```